# Is my method equivalent to my lecturers?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

In lectures we were shown how to 'breakdown' a piece-wise linear function so that it can be used as part of a linear program.

Now, my lecturer wrote the function as $a=f(x)=\max(0,55x-11000)$ and in the program he set  the following constraints:
$$a\ge 0 $$
$$a \ge 55x-11000 $$
And so the objective function was:
$$\text{Maximize } 121p - a $$

Before I saw his solution, I tried this: $b=g(x) = \min(0,11000-55x)$ and I made my constraints to be:
$$b\le0 $$
$$b \le 11000-55x$$
And my objective was:
$$\text{Maximize } 121p+b $$

So is my formulation the same?

EDIT: running simplex on both confirmed they are infact the same. I won't delete this question however, in case someone else can use it as a guide.

Comment: So $g(x)=-f(x)$ and $b=-a$.  Is that enough to make them equivalent?

Comment: @Henry I would think so, but I'm unsure. Particularly if the constraints will handle the same.

Comment: I would think so too.  You can check each constraint etc. has been translated exactly

Comment: I'll try running simplex and see if both have the same optimal solution.

Comment: @Henry running simplex confirmed they are the same. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are using that $-\max(f_1(x),f_2(x)) = \min(-f_1(x),-f_2(x))$ and then you use the hypograph model for $\min$ instead of the epigraph model of $\max$